# invoke-command with invoke-sql -> Problems with Instance Variable

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

I am writing a script for reading remote SQL instances.

I have a problem with the transfer of the ServerInstance Variable.
I just can't find the error.
Does anyone have an idea?

This Command is working:

```
invoke-command -computername computer1 -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance servername\sqlexpress -Database master -Query "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition'), SERVERPROPERTY ('engineedition')"}
```

Result:

```
PSComputerName : computer1
RunspaceId     : 5393f2e0-715c-46c1-9e64-13642c2f031b
Column1        : 14.0.1000.169
Column2        : RTM
Column3        : Express Edition (64-bit)
Column4        : 4
```

This is not working:

```
$Instance="computer1\sqlexpress"
invoke-command -computername computer1 -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database master -Query "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition'), SERVERPROPERTY ('engineedition')"}
```

Error Message:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL `Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
 (provider:Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
enter code here
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: You need use the `-ArgumentList` option to pass the `$Instance`

Comment: Are you running working and non working code from same machine?  $Instance is a string and should work the same using a variable or the actual string.  I do not think using ArguementList in this case is going to make a difference.

Comment: or `$using:instance`